# Trouble determining basis of eigenspace?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-equations

I'm supposed to find the basis for eigenspace of a particular $\lambda$.

Solving the three by three matrix $(3*3)\begin{pmatrix} v_1 \\ v_2 \\ v_3\end{pmatrix} = 0$. I get:
$$6v_1 + v_2 + 2v_3 = 0$$
$$6v_2 -2v_3 = 0$$

I express everything in the free variable $v_3$ because my last row has only $0 's$ (no pivot).
$$v_1 = {7\over 18 }v_3$$
$$v_2 = {1\over 3 }v_3$$

Can someone help me in the final step to represent the basis for eigenspace, I can't get the grip of it..

Comment: Let $v_3=18$ (or any other nonzero number you like – I just chose 18 so there won't be any fractions, since I prefer whole numbers). Then $v_1=7$ and $v_2=6$, so $(7,6,18)$ is a basis for the eigenspace.

Comment: How would you express with variables, and in the form of a matrix, just for visual help. @GerryMyerson

Comment: I don't know what you mean by expressing a basis for the eigenspace in the form of a matrix. A basis isn't a matrix – it's a set of vectors.

Comment: Sorry never mind, i was looking a bit for the answer below. but your answer is also good @GerryMyerson another quick question, when determining $det(A - \lambda)$, it is customary to reduce matrix $A$ to a lower triangle?

Comment: That would depend a bit on the size of $A$. If it's 2-by-2 or 3-by-3, I see no point in reducing to triangular. Maybe there's some advantage for larger matrices.

Comment: @GerryMyerson ok thanks appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Because you derived only one free variable, say $x_3$, the eigenspace 
$E$ is of dimension $1$ and is of the form
\begin{align*}
E=\text{span}\left(\left\{\begin{pmatrix}\frac{7}{18}\\\frac{1}{3}\\1
\end{pmatrix}\right\}\right).
\end{align*}